# Angular async pipe does not work for image source update

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable, async-pipe

in this Angular component, I get an observable of user object, I try to verify on NgInit, whether the profile picture URL is defined. If not, I want to set a placeholder for that. But for some reason, the change I make within ngOnInit is too late. The image source is not set properly, so the result is the alternative text is being displayed. I thought the async pipe will help me to get the image whenever it is newly set? Could someone help me to get a better understanding for this context? :)

```
  @Input()
  user$: Observable<UserProfileData>;

  userSub: Subscription;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.userSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSub = this.user$.subscribe(user=> {
      user.profilePictureUrl = (user.profilePictureUrl) ? user.profilePictureUrl : '/assets/placeholder.png';
      }
    )
  }
```

And in HTML, I simply call the user profile picture with async pipe.

```
<img class="ml-lg-5 mb-2 mb-md-0 mx-auto rounded-circle" src="{{(user$|async).profilePictureUrl}}" alt="{{ (user$|async).username }}">
```

This is what I get for `user$`, it is from an object of UserProfileData:

```
description: "My name is Steve, I look forward to collaborating with you guys!"
firstname: "Steve"
lastname: "Mustermann"
location: LocationModel {country: "Germany", city: "Hamburg", zipcode: "22145"}
occupation: "Barber"
profilePictureUrl: ""
score: "69.1"
username: "steve669"
```

Comment: Why are you subscribing to the observable `user$` both in the component and template?

Comment: is there a way to subscribe in only one place? Feel free to share your approach with me :)

Comment: Yeah. You can choose to do it in either of the places and not both.

Comment: Also, can you share what `user$` returns after subscription?

Comment: if i only want to subscribe in the component, how would I declare it in the template?

Comment: description: "My name is Steve, I look forward to collaborating with you guys!"

firstname: "Steve"

lastname: "Engel"

location: LocationModel {country: "Germany", city: "Hamburg", zipcode: "22145"}

occupation: "Barber"

profilePictureUrl: ""

score: "69.1"

username: "steve669"

Comment: that is what is being returned before value update within subscription

Comment: It doesnt look like a valid json. Could you format it and paste it? Also, you can subscribe in the component and store it in a variable. Next, on the template you can read from this variable once it is ready.

Comment: Once you share the json appropriately, I can show you both ways and then you can decide which one to use :-)

Comment: hehe it's not a json property, but are attributes of the object of UserProfileData :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.user$ = this.user$.pipe(map(user => {
    if (!user.profilePictureUrl) {
      user.profilePictureUrl = '/assets/placeholder.png';
    }

    return user;
  }));
)
```

In the template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
  <img class="ml-lg-5 mb-2 mb-md-0 mx-auto rounded-circle" src="{{user.profilePictureUrl}}" alt="{{ user.username }}">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for this working solution! I have read that .subscribe() doesn't work out with the onPush change detection strategy ootb, but if I'd follow the subscribe approach, how would i make it work too?

Comment: `
 public user: UserProfileData;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.user$.subscribe((user => {
    if (!user.profilePictureUrl) {
      user.profilePictureUrl = '/assets/placeholder.png';
    }

    this.user = user;
  }));
)

`

In template

`  <img class="ml-lg-5 mb-2 mb-md-0 mx-auto rounded-circle" src="{{user.profilePictureUrl}}" alt="{{ user.username }}">
`